# add_action 'manage_posts_custom_column' in a class

Tags: actions, columns, wp-list-table

I think this may be more of a general php question but I am posting it here as it relates to a WP function. I am having some issues with an `add_action` on `manage_posts_custom_column` inside a class. Here is the code (stripped a little):

```
class The_class{

    function __construct() {
        $this->add_actions();
    }

    function add_actions() {
        add_action('admin_notices', array($this, 'admin_notices'));
        add_action('manage_posts_custom_column', array($this, 'manage_post_columns', 10, 2));
    }

    function admin_notices() {
    // Works fine
    }

    function manage_post_columns($column_name, $post_id)
        switch ($column_name) {
            case 'xxxyyzz':
                // The code                                 
            break;      
            default:
                // Error
            break;
        }   
    }
}
```

The error I am getting is `Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, array must have exactly two members in xxx/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 405`.

Looking deeper I found that the action `manage_posts_custom_column` is referenced in the `WP_Posts_List_Table` class that extends `WP_List_Table` and I wonder if this is the cause of the error?

How do I get around this?

**Edit:**

Well for starters I could write the action properly!!!
Instead of `add_action('manage_posts_custom_column', array($this, 'manage_post_columns', 10, 2));` it should be `add_action('manage_posts_custom_column', array($this, 'manage_post_columns'), 10, 2);`. Note the position of the `)`. :-)

Comment: Helped, but close voted as typos won't help.

Comment: Actually - this isn't as localized an issue as some of us would like to admit.  After wasting 20 minutes on this I found Niels question and edit VERY helpful as I had made the same mistake.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your problem is a simple typo:

> `array($this, 'manage_post_columns', 10, 2)`
>
> **VS.**
>
> `array($this, 'manage_post_columns'), 10, 2`

I guess you see the difference

Comment: Great catch Kaiser.